# Android data binding with <include> tag in the library module

Tags: java, android, data-binding, include, android-databinding

In my project I have multiple modules, let's say module app and module A that act as a library for module app. I use data binding and works fine by adding

`dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}`

in each module build.gradle.

The problem occurred when I use `<include>` tag in the layout of module A . It crashing when calling setContentView from DataBindingUtil.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.package.name.databinding.ViewToolbarBinding.invalidateAll()' on a null object reference

However It works fine in the module app, I am able to access the view by using something like this.

```
mBindingUtil.includedLayout.viewInTheIncludedLayout
```

This is my activity layout in module A :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/view_toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"/>

</LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

And this is my view_toolbar.xml in module A :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/primary_blue"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:elevation="0dp" />

</layout>
```

While this is how I inflate the activity in module A :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_with_include);
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should inflate a view that is using data binding by using `DataBindingUtil.inflate` instead of `DataBindingUtil.setContentView`:

```
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.yourlayoutfile, container, false);
        //viewmodel assigned in oncreate()
        mBinding.setViewModel(yourViewModel);
        return mBinding.getRoot();
    }
```

If you look at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/DataBindingUtil.html#setContentView(android.app.Activity,%20int)), you will see that the method for `DataBindingUtil.setContentView`  says:

> Set the Activity's content view to the given layout and return the
>   associated binding. The given layout resource must not be a merge
>   layout.

I think it safe to assume that this includes `include` tags. So if you use the `DataBindingUtil.inflate` you should be safe. You should also note that any of the UI setup should be done in the `onCreateView()` rather than `onCreate()`.

Comment: Thank you. However, this will only works on fragment. I've tried it on activity and its not working.